# Universally suppressing Django signal's errors?

Tags: python, django

We have a few Django post-save signals on the user object which call external dependencies (CRMs, mail providers, etc). These calls are nice-to-haves and shouldn't block or error the user if they happen.

The libraries have various error states (can't connect to external service, bad key, etc), and it was a pain to model, so I made an exception-suppressing decorator I can apply to the signal(s) so they never block.

```
def exception_suppressor()
    def suppressor(*args, **kwargs):
         try:
             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
         except Exception as e:
             LOGGER.info("Suppressing exception: " + str(e))
     return suppressor
```

1. Is this widely done? Are there better ways of doing it?
2. Are there any builtins that can provide this? I saw some
   with-context-block construct that allowed this, but not a decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. I have used try-except-else blocks in a lot of projects and it has saved me a lot of pain. I am no expert in Python so I'm not sure if there are better ways of doing this, but this code should be good enough.